# Rxjava: observeOn affects observer's disposal logic

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following example:

```
private var dis: Disposable? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
    val btn2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2)

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        dis = Single.fromCallable {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            15
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        //.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ v ->
            log("Success: $v")
        }, { e ->
            log("Error: $e")
        })
    }

    btn2.setOnClickListener {
        dis?.dispose()
    }
}

fun log(msg: String) {
    Log.d("TAGG", msg + " on " + Thread.currentThread().name);
}
```

When ".observeOn(..)" line is COMMENTED and I:

1. press btn
2. press btn2 immediately after pressing btn

Then observer's onError block of code WILL be called.

When ".observeOn(..)" line UNCOMMENTED and I:

1. press btn
2. press btn2 immediately after pressing btn

Then observer's onError block of code WILL NOT be called.

I just can not understand such behaviour. In my understanding this line of code shouldn't affect logic of whether onError will be called or not.

Why does this happen? Is this documented behaviour? Please, give me some explanation or redirects.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code is really, really bad practice. 1) You are changing a field in one thread and testing it in another -- this won't end well. It is why your results are so confusing. 2) Disposables are disposed for a reason: you should be calling `dispose()` and then testing for `isDisposed()` on your disposable.

Comment: Yes, it is clear, why an error is shown. It was made intentionally. The question is about why this error is shown in one case and is not shown in another, why same behaviour is not preserved by rxjava.

Comment: Okay, i've simplified the code, to make my question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

By using a unit test, I do not reproduce your issue. With or without observeOn, I observe an UndeliverableException thrown to RxJavaPlugins and the doOnDispose called.

What do you see?

```
@Test
  public void testObserveOnEffect() throws Exception {
    Disposable dis = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      return 15;
    })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnDispose(() -> logThread("dispose"))
        .subscribe(v -> logThread(v), e -> logThread(e));

    Single.timer(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(o -> dis.dispose());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `observeOn` line and disposable is disposed the RxJava will interrupt flow before trying to deliver result to the subscriber.

Here is the issue link https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4673